# How to set .as and .hx files to open with FDT Powerflasher

Tags: haxe, fdt

Is it possible to set .as and .hx to open with FDT Powerflasher? Settings it to open with what seems to be a previously detected by Windows eclipse.exe (my Java one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special with as/hx files, same procedure as with any other file extension:

1. Right click on file
2. Open with...
3. Choose the application
4. Check "Always use the selected program ..."
5. Ok.